# Acumatica API Login Limit Exceeded

Tags: acumatica

I am using web services to create Stock Items and Sales Order. I am facing an issue when I log in I get the following error message "API LOGIN LIMIT EXCEEDED". I cannot reduce the number of login requests. Is there a way to increase the API Login Limit.

Comment: The limit is tied to the license. If not licensed then i thing the API login limit to 1 i think starting in 2018R1 (even though user login is 2). Make sure when you are done you logout in your api call so you can login next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brendan is correct, you might be simulating on multiple devices/instances. Just make sure you logout on your code block when doing something on the Specific Screen or Page