# Acumatica API login limit in developent

Tags: javascript, api, acumatica

I am developing a web application which calls the Acumatica API with an extended endpoint. I have a small license applied which I realize has API limits, but what I am trying to understand is the API login limit. I am the only one using the endpoint but after making several consecutive requests I often hit this API login limit.

Since I am only logging in once, and then making consecutive requests, why would I be getting a login limit exception?

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987420/acumatica-api-login-limit-exceeded

Comment: Try using Postman and see if you run into the same problem. I haven't been able to reproduce this so I think it is how you are calling the API from your application. Can you post the web application code where it opens the connection and the loop?

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure you log out at the end of your process. If you don't subsequent calls will consume an additional user. when you log out it will release the login that you just consumed.

Comment: I have a chain of requests in javascript. I should log out and log back in for each one?

Comment: @sreimer you don't need to log in/out for each one. I would suggest logging in before sending the first request of the chain and log out after the last request of the chain, or if any of the requests fails and you won't continue sending requests.

Comment: You only need to log out when everything is done. you can call as much as you need in between and only consume one API user.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you application finished it execution that it does perform a logout request.

If you do not the next time that you start the application it will not remember the previous session that you opened and will thus use another spot allowed by the license.

If you do this to frequently then you will reach the license limit.

If you were to use the Postman Application you might not encounter this issue as Postman store the session in cookies and remember it throughout all the request that you will be making.